# How to multiply rows based on condition in sql

Tags: sql, mysql, oracle

I have a table at a customer ID level where I need to group by customer ID and multiply different values in  row & column.

Eg:

| Id | Qnt |
| --- | --- |
| ab1234 | 20 |
| xy123 | 30 |
| gh123 | 10 |

| ID | CAP | MKT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ab1234 | 1 | 2 |
| xy123 | 1 | 5 |
| xy123 | 2 | 2 |
| gh123 | 1 | 5 |
| xy123 | 3 | 0.5 |

Expected output
When ID = xy123
Then I should get below record

| ID | QNT | CAP | MKT | CAP | MKT | OUT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xy123 | 30 | 1 | 5 | 2 | 2 | 600 |

Note : Consider only 1 & 2 in cap column

When ID = gh123

| ID | QNT | CAP | MKT | CAP | MKT | OUT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| gh123 | 10 | 1 | 5 | 1 | 5 | 50 |

When cap is only 1 for ID =gh123 then multiply qnt*b.cap*b.mkt
Which is 10*1*5 = 50

```
Select a.id,
       b.cap,
       b.mkt,
       c.cap,
       c.mkt,
       (a.qnt*a.cap*a.mkt*b.cap*b.mkt) as output
From   table1 a
       Left join table2 b On a.id = b.id
       Inner join table2 c On b.id=c.id
Where  b.cap=1
and    c.cap=2
and    a.id = 'xy123';
```

This code works for xy123 where cap is 1 and 2 but doesn't work for id gh123.

Need SQL query and I'm not looking for PL/SQL or using cursors.

Comment: MySQL and Oracle are two different RDBMS with different syntaxes; which one are you using?

Comment: Please do not ask the same question twice. If this really is a different question then [edit] your question and explain what the difference is to your previous question (because it looks identical).

Comment: @MT0 - the formatting was not proper in previous question.

Comment: Then fix the previous question, don't ask a new one.